# how to remove these '&quot;' in django template 

Tags: javascript, python, django

this is my code in `homepage.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var jstree_jsondata={{json1}};
 alert(typeof jstree_jsondata)
</script>
```

and it show this in the source code :

```
var jstree_jsondata=
  [
   { &quot;data&quot; : &quot;kkkqq node&quot;, 
    &quot;attr&quot; : { &quot;id&quot; : &quot;ooo&quot; ,&quot;time&quot;:&quot;pp&quot;},
    metadata:&quot;i am the one&quot;,
    children&quot; : [ 
        {
```

so how to remove all of the `&quot;`  using django ,

thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Change the line:

```
var jstree_jsondata={{json1}}
```

to

```
var jstree_jsondata={{ json1|safe }}
```

This uses the `safe` filter to tell Django that the contents should be output literally without changing characters to html entities. The reason for the name 'safe' is that you are declaring that the data to be output is safe and will not be the origin of potential cross site scripting attacks or html that will break your layout.

Comment: and you also should always add a space after "{{" and before "}}". So {{ json1|safe }} would be the preferred way to do that.

Comment: I would have spent my life looking for this. Thanks a ton!